# Using parfor Loops on matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, parfor

I am using parfor for parallel computing in Matlab. I am not familiar with this command. If that is possible, please look at my code below and tell me if I can write it with parfor. The error : 
The parfor loop cannot be run due to the way variable pyra is used.

```
parfor i = 1:inter
  scaled = resize(im, 1/sc^(i-1));
  pyra.feat{i} = descripteurs(scaled,class);

   pyra.scale(i) = 1/sc^(i-1);

  for j = i+inter:inter:max_scale
    scaled = reduce(scaled);
    pyra.feat{j} = descripteurs(scaled,class);
    pyra.scale(j) = 0.6 * pyra.scale(j-inter);
  end
end
```

Comment: You should start with the Mathworks own [extensive documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/variables-in-parfor-loops.html) on variable usage within a `parfor` loop

Comment: I tried to proceed by changes as indicated on the documentation but I still have problems.

Comment: Please , how can I proceed to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your code is *not* parallelizable since each iteration through the `parfor` loop depends on other iterations of the loop.

Specifically, you're trying to access values of `pyra.scale` from within the inner loop that were computed on previous iterations through the outer loop. Because of this, the execution of each iteration of the  `parfor` loop is dependent upon the previous iteration and therefore the two iterations cannot be executed in parallel (at the same time).

See more about the use of variables in `parfor` loops in [the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/variables-in-parfor-loops.html).